# Export DataTables Child Rows in CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, datatables, export

I have a datatable showing child rows as in the following example:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Have added the export functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

But the content in the child rows is not exporting only the header row.

What should be done to have child rows. 
(Note my child rows are just like the parent rows - but this should not really matter)

Found the following issue on their site (which is exactly what i need):
https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/715

But does not seem like they have an answer. Reaching out here to learn if anyone has any suggestions

Comment: Create hidden rows with the required data.

Comment: @thejavaguy, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: unfortunatelly not @tmthyjames

Comment: I have found this [link](https://datatables.net//forums/discussion/43133) in the forums but not tested it out yet